# Estimate number of bidders above a price threshold

Tags: estimation, distributions

I am working on a project on an online auction system and we had an idea about estimate the number of bidders above a certain price threshold. The concept of the auction is:

1. We have a number $p$ of a certain product
2. We have $max$ the max price and $min$ the min price (which is typically zero)
3. There is a price threshold $t⊂[min,max]$
4. People come and bid during the day (one bid per person)
5. The auction stops at the end of the day or when the number of bidders above $t$ is bigger than $p$
6. The bidders above $t$ buy the product

The information that is available to us is the past history of bids on similar products. Similar products meaning we can consider there is a more or less strong correlation between those sales and our future sale we want to estimate.

The main question is can we estimate the number of bidders above $t$ with a certain probability to it? And if yes how?

The main problem I see is in using past history, since, of course we use only similar products' history, but still the $max$ price is different and the threshold $t$ is not the same ratio of the $max$. Sometime let's say $t = 0.4*max$ and other time it may be $t = 0.33*max$.

One idea I had around this is that clients are not aware of the threshold, thus it does not influence their bids. The only thing I have to do is normalise all the bids. I would have $bids⊂[0;1]$ for all historic sales. With this information I could use Matlab or something else to estimate the $pdf$ or $cdf$ of bids (kernel smoothing).

And this is where I am kind of stuck conceptually. For me the $cdf$ can give me the probability that one bid is above the normalised threshold $t$ (correct me if I am wrong).
But I don't know how to get from this to what we want i.e. the number of bidders above $t$ for a future sale.

**Update:** since a person can bid only once (a person = one bid) and my $cdf = P(Y<y) = $ one bid below $y$, I just have to scale this $cdf$ to give me $N$ bids below $y$. Is this possible simply by multiplying $N*P(Y<y)$, which will no longer be the probability, but directly the number of bids $<y$? Or should I somehow derive another random variable from $Y$ that will represent multiple bids
If it is the second option, I don't really know how to do that, so if you have any ideas, they are welcome.

Thanks for any help and if anything is not clear enough please comment I will edit with more information if I can.